# pam_ssh_agent_auth - No ssh-agent could be contacted

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, pam

I am struggling to get pam_ssh_agent_auth to work on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

In `/etc/sudoers` I have added

```
Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

and in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`

```
auth sufficient pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/ssh/sudo_authorized_keys
```

However, I am still required to provide a password when sudo'ing.

`/var/log/auth.log` says:

```
Beginning pam_ssh_agent_auth for user myuser
pam_ssh_agent_auth: Attempting authentication: `myuser' as `myuser' using /etc/ssh/sudo_authorized_keys
pam_ssh_agent_auth: No ssh-agent could be contacted
pam_ssh_agent_auth: Failed Authentication: `myuser' as `myuser' using /etc/ssh/sudo_authorized_keys
```

I am using putty to ssh to my server and `Allow agent forwarding` is enabled.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to not actually running **Pageant** on the computer.  You need to add your PPK into Pageant on Windows, and have it running.

There is an option in PuTTY to use Pageant to login first:

**Connection > SSH > Auth** that is checked by default **Attempt authentication using Pageant**.  Make sure that is checked.